# Setting a computed value (struct vs class)

Tags: ios, swift

I made a simple struct that handles the management of the UI background (the user can choose to use a gradient or image).  Inside this struct is a computed property called `preference` which gets and sets the user's preference to UserDefaults.

When I try to *set* the `preference` property using the following code:

`Background().preference = .gradient`

I get an error: "Cannot assign to property: function call returns immutable value"

I have to use this instead:

`var background = Background()
background.preference = .gradient`

I would prefer not having to assign an instance of `Background` to a variable before finally setting the property.

I've found that changing `Background` from a `struct` to a `class` allows me to set the property using `Background().preference = .gradient` directly.

Can anyone give me some insight as to why this occurs?  Is using `class` better than using `struct` for this situation or does it not matter?

```
struct Background {

enum Choice {
    case gradient
    case image
}

var preference: Choice {

    get {
        if let type = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "background_type"), type as! String == "background" {
           return .image
        }
        return .gradient
    }

    set(value){
        if value == .image {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue("background", forKey: "background_type")
        }else{
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue("gradient", forKey: "background_type")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each call to `Background()` creates a new `Background` instance, for the sole (temporary) use of accessing/setting `UserDefault` values, whereafter you throw away the particular `Background` instance. I.e., you currenly have a value type which doesn't store anything itself, only provides an access interface to some particular `UserDefault`:s. Perhaps you'd rather like to use a singleton or pure type properties/methods (to replace `preference`) here? (Note that letting `Background` be a class still have the same issue: you construct instances on-the-fly that doesn't own any data themselves)

Answer (score 1):

You're not really getting any value from making an instance of a struct / class to just wrap UserDefaults. It's a very common problem and there are lots of clever solutions out there on google if you search around. For a really simple example you could just extend UserDefaults

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa


enum BackgroundChoice {
    case gradient
    case image
}

extension UserDefaults {

    var backgroundChoice: BackgroundChoice {
        get {
            if let type = string(forKey: "background_type"), type == "image" {
                return .image
            }
            return .gradient
        }

        set(value){
            if value == .image {
                setValue("background", forKey: "background_type")
            }else{
                setValue("gradient", forKey: "background_type")
            }
        }
    }

}

UserDefaults.standard.backgroundChoice = .image
```

I know this doesn't answer your exact question, but I think you'll find there are better solutions to this problem if you dig around.

Comment: My goal was to move this type of code out of the view controllers into separate files to both reduce the size and improve testability.  Extensions look really helpful in that regard. Thanks.